# Python - apply lambda with an if condition

Tags: python, pandas

I want to transform a `pandas` column that contains `Nan` from string to float. This is the code I tried but it keeps returning me an invalid syntax error

```
data.VAL_DEAL=data.VAL_DEAL.apply(lambda x: float(x.replace(",","")) if math.isnan(x)!=True)
```

Comment: You can just do `df['VAL_DEAL'] = pd.to_numeric(df['VAL_DEAL'], errors='coerce')`, there is no need to use `apply` here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following lambda expression should work:

```
lambda x: float(x.replace(",","") if not math.isnan(x) else x)
```

Note the mandatory `else`-part. This assumes that you want the nan's unchanged. See the docs on [Conditional Expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions).